# How do I center 2 buttons?

Tags: html, css

How do I center the Border Childs With text content in it?

I want to center my button like :

```
   text1text
     text2
```

[Picture Captured Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8IT7.png)

Here's what I tried:

```css
.btn {
    margin-bottom: 5rem;

    width: fit-content;

    border-radius: 2.5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;

  

    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="btn">testestest</h1>
<h1 class="btn">testest</h1>
```

Comment: Your css is centering within each button, but the buttons themselves need to be centered. Use text-align on the buttons' container.

Comment: You can edit your post to fix the typo if that's not the cause of the problem (if it is the cause, then the question can be deleted)

Comment: @DextolReiniger3000: If you've discovered a typo in your code which resolved the issue then it's best to just delete this question as it will be of little use to future readers.

Comment: @David Okay thank you. i corrected the typo in the Question ! .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to wrap your h1 tags inside another div element

```css
.btn {
    margin-bottom: 5rem;

    width: fit-content;

    border-radius: 2.5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}


.btn-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <h1 class="btn">testestest</h1>
  <h1 class="btn">testest</h1>
 <div>
```

This is one way to do it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your left and right margins to auto:

```css
.btn {
  margin: auto auto 5rem auto;
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="btn">testestest</h1>
<h1 class="btn">testest</h1>
```